# Selenium can`t find element - "connect" button in LinkedIn

Tags: python, selenium

Hey guys I am working on an automating bot for adding connections in LinkedIn, recently I encountered a problem for finding the "Connect" element(button) after searching in the search box and filtering for "People only".

**That is the inspect of the relevant part:**

```
<div id="ember374" class="ember-view">   
  <button id="ember378" class="artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--secondary ember-view" data-control-name="entity_action_primary" data-control-id="AQT4G2UkQk6LQlbdf6XySw==">
    <!---->
    <span class="artdeco-button__text">Connect</span></button>
```

**This is my tries for clicking on that "connect" element:**

```
1. CONNECT_BUTTON_SEARCH_PAGE = "//*[contains(@class,'artdeco-button__text') and contains(.,'Connect')]"

2. CONNECT_BUTTON_SEARCH_PAGE = "//*[text()='Connect']"

3. CONNECT_BUTTON_SEARCH_PAGE = "//button[contains(. , ’Connect’)]"

WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                        (By.XPATH, Xpath.CONNECT_BUTTON_SEARCH_PAGE))).click()
```

**I have to mention that it works fine in the "Network" page, but I want it to add connections after searching a key word. So when I'm searching people according to a special key word, in that page I don't find the "Connect" button**

I don`t know why but I can not reach for that element, appreciate if someone could help me

Comment: Why didn´t you select by Id?

Comment: Because it's changing by every person. Am I wrong?

Comment: So how do i am implement that? @arundeepchohan

Comment: The first implementation didnt work. The second, should i put this after the "//*span[text()='Connect'] ? sry but im not know much about this preceding sibling @arundeepchohan

Comment: Thanks man but still does`nt work. Any other ideas? u can see the edited html @arundeepchohan

Comment: //span[text()='Connect']/ancestor::button Oh remove the *.

Comment: Unfortunately it`s still not finding the element @arundeepchohan

Comment: //button/span[text()='Connect']/.. How about this one.

Comment: Try increasing the wait time from 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks man but still not working. Not with this implementation and even with more then 5 sec. I dont know what else can i do @arundeepchohan

Comment: Nope @arundeepchohan

Comment: I have to mention that it works fine in the "Network" page, but I want it to add connections after searching a key word. So when I'm searching people according to a special key word, in that page I don't find the "Connect" button @arundeepchohan

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly found a (weird) soulution with the help of @arundeepchohan.

First I used this xpath:

```
"//button/span[text()='Connect']/.."
```

But then I had to "refresh" the page before trying to click the "connect" button. I don't have an explanation for that to work and why it was necessary to refresh the page, but I used this part of code before the clicking method:

```
time.sleep(2)
self.driver.get(self.driver.current_url)
```

Thanks for everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath :

```
//button[contains(. , ’Connect’)]
```

Comment: Thanks but it does`nt work. any other ideas? @YourHelper

Comment: Actually there is no way if the button contains this asa text what is the error?

Comment: nothing happens. its keep progressing in my code and doesnt find the element(wo`nt click on the "connect") button @YourHelper

Comment: Instead of the click() method try this : sendKeyd(Keys,ENTER); to the xpath that I mentioned before